# how to set datarow to String array?

Tags: asp.net, arrays, datarow

I have a datatable on which I am applying **Select()** method. After that I want to get the result into an array of  String. I have tried the following code but it is not working.
Please let me know the exact solutions for this.

```
 DataTable dtget = HttpContext.Current.Cache["Hello"] as DataTable; 
    string sqlFilter = "Securityid = '" + CommonClass.Encryptdata(txtSecurity.Text) + "'";
    DataRow[] dr = dtget.Select(sqlFilter);
    if (dr.Length > 0)
    {
        String[] Con;
        for (int i = 0; i <= dr.Length; i++)
        {
            dr[i] = dr[i].ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You need two `for` blocks: the outer one cycles on the number of row returned by the `Select()` method, the inner one cycles on the number of columns in the datatable. Moreover, you have to initialize a bidimensional array: `String[] Con = new String[dr.length, dtget.Columns.count];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the `List<T>`.

Something like this:

```
 List<String[]> list=new List<String[]>();

   if (dr.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dr.Length; i++)
        {
            string []ar=new string[dtget.Columns.Count];
            for(int j=0;j<dtget.Columns.Count;j++)
             {
              ar[j]=dr[i][j].ToString();
             }
             list.Add(ar);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its throwing error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.DataRow'" At "dr[i] = dr[i].ToString();"

Comment: That's becuase you wrote `dr[i] = dr[i].ToString();` in stead of `Con[i] = dr[i].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the array, but not instantiated it. and you're also not writing anything to the actual array, you're trying to write straight back to the datatable.

```
String[] Con= new String[dtget.Columns.Count]; 
for (int i = 0; i <= dr.Length; i++) 
{ 
    Con[i] = dr[i].ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning values to the datarrow in stead of to your string array.
Change

```
dr[i] = dr[i].ToString();
```

to

```
con[i] = dr[i].ToString();
```

also you are missing the new statement for Con:

```
Con = new String[dr.Table.Columns.Count];
```

notice that there is no such thing as dr.Length, you have to check for the column count:

```
dr.Table.Columns.Count
```

lastly, you should probably move the string array definition up so it's available outside the IF.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, what you could do is use the Datarow's ItemArray property. It is an object array in stead of a string array, but before using it's values you can do a "ToString()" and you are all set.

```
string a = dr.ItemArray[i].ToString();
```